# What does accessing child elements internally or accessing directly mean in composite pattern?

Tags: design-patterns, object-oriented-design, software

I am reading the book "design patterns: elements of reusable object oriented software. And I am trying to understand the composite pattern. I need help in understanding this paragraph in the case study part of the book

> Glyphs like Row  that  can  have  children  should  use  Child internally  instead  of  accessing  the child  data  structure  directly.  That  way you  won't  have  to  modify  operations  like Draw  that  iterate through  the  children  when  you  change  the  data  structure  from, say,  an  array to  a  linked  list.  Similarly,  Parent  provides  a  standard  interface to the  glyph's  parent,  if  any.  Glyphs  in  Lexi  store  a  reference  to their  parent,  and their  Parent  operation  simply returns  this reference.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Does the Composite design pattern implement recursive behavior?](http://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/233411/does-the-composite-design-pattern-implement-recursive-behavior)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Glyphs like Row that can have children should use Child internally instead of accessing the child data structure directly.

A composite pattern exposes some operation that when called will be performed on the composite node and any and all sub nodes, and their sub nodes, and their ... you get the idea. This passage is saying that the client using the node (by calling this operation) shouldn't have to deal with traversing sub nodes. It shouldn't even know if there are sub nodes. It should just call the operation and expect the composite node to figure out the rest.

> That way you won't have to modify operations like Draw that iterate through the children when you change the data structure from, say, an array to a linked list.

If the client doesn't do the traversing it won't need to change when the traversal needs change. That's important when there are many clients.

> Similarly, Parent provides a standard interface to the glyph's parent, if any. Glyphs in Lexi store a reference to their parent, and their Parent operation simply returns this reference.

Parent, however, is making you deal a traversal detail. But at least it's a standardized traversal detail.